# Thread to store log data in database of JBoss application

Tags: java, database, multithreading, jboss

I have a service method that requires storing some log data on a database. If this method is invoked very frequently from many clients, there may be no more connections available from the datasource connection pool to the database: this causes a wait by some clients.

Since the storage of log data is not strictly essential for the service working correctly, I would make sure that storing log data is handled by a dedicated thread, in order to reduce the clients waiting for response.

For example, I could use Java [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).
Or, would it be better to use a different approach in a JBoss application server?

Comment: what logging framework are you using?  Both logback and log4j have asychronous appenders you can wrap around JDBC appenders to achieve what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: What version of JBoss AS/JBoss EAP or WildFly are you using?